# Raid - "Rebuilding up" the storage

Tags: raid

Say I have a RAID 1 config of two 1TB drives. (1TB of storage)

I take one out, insert a 2TD drive and let it rebuild. (Still 1TB of storage)

Now I take the second one out, and insert a 2TB drive and let it rebuild.

Do I end up with 2 TB of available storage, or just 1TB, from the original configuration?

Does the answer change for RAID 5 or 6?

Comment: Yes. Try [searching](http://serverfault.com/search?q=%2Braid+%2Blarger&submit=search). Also please read the FAQ; we don't usually like hypothetical questions here.

Comment: Hey Michael. Thanks! That's a great tip! And it also doesn't make me feel dumb at all, because it never crossed my mind to search for the answer on the "internet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you will end with the same storage space, and this doesn't change with R5 or R6.

However, you *can* increase the storage space afterwards, but this is a rather delicate procedure.

You need to

- Enlarge the RAID partitions.
- Tell the RAID driver to use the additional space.
- Grow the filesystems

If you google it, I am sure you will find a lot of guides how to do this  in detail.

Comment: Hint: I oriented my answer around a software RAID, but it's not really different with a hardware RAID controller.

Answer (score 2):

A logical disk (LUN) does not automatically increase in size. Depending on RAID controller you can increase the size, or create a second logical disk with 1TB of new storage.

The answer is the same for any RAID level.